# Combing a select statement with a count on a different table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: users and lessons.

Currently I select all the users using:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_type = 1;
```

Then use PHP to loop through them and count their number of lessons using

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lessons WHERE student_id=users.user_id;
```

I would like to combine this into a single query and I'm pretty sure this is possible with a JOIN but it is beyond my basic SQL knowledge.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this all in one query.  If you want a count per user:

```
select u.user_id, count(l.student_id)
from users u left join
     lessons l
     on u.user_id = l.student_id
where u.user_type = 1
group by u.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a join, or a correlated subquery:

```
select 
    u.*,
    (select count(*) from lessons l where l.student_id = u.user_id) no_lessons
from users u
```

The upside of the subquery solution is that it does not require aggregation in the outer query. With an index on `lessons(student_id)`, this should be an efficient option.

Comment: Thanks. This works but in my tests takes about 10x longer to execute.

Comment: @AlexRees: do you have the suggested index in place?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the following query for this:

```
SELECT * FROM users u LEFT JOIN lessons l ON u.user_id=l.student_id WHERE u.user_type=1 GROUP BY u.user_id
```

This will join both the tables (users and lessons) based on the id of both tables and the GROUP BY clause will group all the records of same id as you just want the number of lessons per user.